# How to load Grafana dashboards to a folder on startup?

Tags: grafana

Trying to group Grafana dashboards in to a folder when grafana server starts, i can get dashboard and folder id/name, but need to configure it to move dashboards to a specific folder,
please suggest me.

Answer (score 8):

To add dashboards to a folder on server startup you need to add the dashboard configuration through provisioning https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#dashboards

You need to specify the folder attribute in the dashboard.yml provider config

example: dashboard.yml

```
apiVersion: 1
providers:
- name: general
  # leave empty for general folder
  folder: ''
  type: file
  disableDeletion: true
  editable: true
  options:
    path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/general

- name: admin
  folder: 'admin'
  type: file
  disableDeletion: true
  editable: true
  options:
    path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/admin
```

Then inside /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/general you create .json files containing the json model of your dashboards from the grafana edit dashboard page and it will load all .json dashboard files into that folder